# What is the smallest possible number of vertices you can create a prism graph from?

Tags: graph-theory

I understand how to draw prism graphs that have 3 or more vertices (surrounded by another 3 of course) but I am struggling with those that have just 2 and 1. This because what I have looks more like a diamond  rather than a prism. I just want to confirm if three is the lowest I can go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider that a prism graph is a representation of a polyhedron and that if such a polyhedron is a prism, two opposite faces have the same number of edges and their linking faces must have four sides, and consider that prism graphs aren't digraphs, then the smallest prism graph is the graph
$$Y_2=\text{GP}(2,1)$$

Which represents the tetragonal dihedron, Schlafli symbol $\{4,2\}$